# How to add padding to images/chart in MS Word with 'in line with text' wrapping?

Tags: microsoft-word, charts, microsoft-word-2007

I have a justified paragraph at the end of a two column page. On inserting a chart with "in line with text" mode under text wrapping in the middle of the paragraph, the image appears fine.

How can I add spacing (padding) just above the image as below without using <kbd>Enter</kbd> key?

If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the justified text is not justified anymore and the lines following the image of the same paragraph doesn't seem continuous.

*In the image below, I want to add spacing after 'was' keeping the paragraph justified (with 'was' on the extreme right').*

[image]

*On pressing enter the spacing is added which I want but the text is not justified anymore.*

[image]

Is there a work around this in Microsoft Word 2007? I don't mind changing the text wrapping mode if that solves the problem.

Comment: What happens if you use <shift>+<enter> instead of <enter>?

Comment: No problem. Added as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### On pressing enter the spacing is added which I want, but the text is not justified anymore.

Use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>enter</kbd>.

This will insert a line break instead of a carriage return and preserve the justified text of the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 6):

In Word 2010 you can set the wrapping style to "top and bottom", which unlocks the "Distance from text" setting.  Not sure if this is in 2007, too, though.

[image]